# what will spring do when i pass null to the controller's param

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a question about the springmvc.
I'm using java record.
which is like:

```
public record LoginParam(String username,String password){}
```

and i want to do something in the controller

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public String login(LoginParam loginParam){
   System.out.println(loginParam)
}
```

i do postmapping like:
`post http://localhost:8080/login` with no body
and the output is:
`loginParam(username=null,password=null).`

why is it not throwing exception,and i'm using Record so it only contains a full constructor,may be it construct like:`LoginParam loginParam=new LoginParam(null,null)`?
where can i find the source code related to it?

Comment: You can use the @Valid annotation to validate the form input. see also https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Comment: [link] https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Record.html

You have a lot of way for fix it
1. You can prevent jackson from serializing null
2. You can use NotNull in recorder class
3. You can use Valid